# Difference between cy.then(() => func()) and cy.wrap(null).then(() => func())

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, cypress

I'm struggling with waiting for async functions to finish. In particular, I found these two methods to wait for completion of an async function before the test continues but don't know the difference (if there is one):

```js
cy.then(() => myAsyncFunction())
```

```js
cy.wrap(null).then(() => myAsyncFunction())
```

My goal is to wait for two async functions in the `beforeEach()` block before the actual tests start:

```js
beforeEach(() => {
    myAsyncFunction1() // This function has to be completed before the next one starts
    myAsyncFunction2() // This function has to be completed before the test continues
    // Only when myAsyncFunction2() has completed the actual tests should start
});
```

I tried to Google for the difference and took a look in the documentation for Cypress but sadly didn't find an answer for how this behaves.

Comment: Why not just write an async hook and await them? You're not actually trying to interleave this with any Cypress commands.

Answer (score 1):

There is **no difference** between the two calls. `cy.then()` is an undocumented shorter form of `cy.wrap(something).then()`.

`cy.then()` will **not wait** for asynchronous functions to finish in the way you are asking.

If you want `myAsyncFunction2()` to wait for `myAsyncFunction1()`, you would use normal javascript patterns - but it depends entirely on what is inside those functions.

`cy.then()` is useful to wait for the command queue to finish, particularly when the commands modify a closure variable.

```js
let result;
cy.get(selector).then($el => result = $el.text())
cy.then(() => {
  cy.log(result)    // logs the element text
})
```

Cypress prefers not to use closure variables, since many people have trouble understanding why the value isn't updated in sequence. Instead they provide an `alias` feature to handle asynchronous variables.

Please read [Variables and aliases](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/core-concepts/variables-and-aliases) for more info.

---

#### Waiting for the asynchronous functions

As long as `myAsyncFunction*()` returns a promise, you just need to return that promise from `beforeEach()`.

Cypress always waits for returned promises to complete before moving to the next command.

```js
beforeEach(() => {
  return myAsyncFunction1().then(() => {
    return myAsyncFunction2()      // promise returned here will be awaited
  })
})
```